# how to optimize a JavaScript random normal generation algo

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, statistics

Here is my code. This function returns a number that follows the standard normal distribution.

```
var rnorm = function() {
  var n = 1000;
  var x = 0;
  var ss = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var a = Math.random();
    x += a;
    ss += Math.pow(a-0.5, 2);
  }
  var xbar = x/n;
  var v = ss/n;
  var sd = Math.sqrt(v);  

  return (xbar-0.5)/(sd/Math.sqrt(n));
};
```

It is simple and exploits the central limit theorem. Here is a jsfiddle running this thing 100,000 times and printing some info to the console.

https://jsfiddle.net/qx61fqpn/

It looks about right (I haven't written code to draw a histogram yet). The right proportions appear between (-1, 1), (-2, 2), (-3, 3) and beyond. The sample mean is 0, var & sd are 1, skew is 0 and kurtosis is 3.

But it's kind of slow.

I intend to write more complex functions using this one as a building block (like the chi-sq distribution).

My question is:

How can I rewrite this code to improve its performance? I'm talking speed. Right now, it's written to be clear to someone with a bit of JavaScript and statistics knowledge what I'm doing (or trying to do - in the event I've done it wrong).

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: He isn't asking for "improvements" in a general sense, but rather, how he could make it run faster.

Some things to tackle are the loop, the power and sqrt.

I know there are implementations of "fast square root" used in graphics, but I think the best would be for you to measure which part of your algorithm take the most time (I suspect the loop & sqrt)

Comment: So then I think I'll start by timing different parts to see what takes the longest then go from there.

Comment: You can also try to: (1) Pre-calculate 1/n and 1/sqrt(n) and then multiply instead of divide. (2) Use `while (n--)` for the loop. (3) Calculate `aa = a - 0.5` and then `aa * aa` instead of calling the Math.pow.

Comment: I'm timing it by using Date.now() before and after a loop executing this fn 10,000 times. The avg time per call is 30 microseconds. Neither the while loop nor replacing Math.pow(a, 2) with a*a have made a difference.